# Mootools 1.2.4, getElements('.selector') not working in IE 9

Tags: internet-explorer-9, mootools

I am using Mootools 1.2.4 and IE 9.
Mootools class selector does not work in IE 9(the following commands). It cannot find the input elements with class="selector".

js code:

```
$('indvNameId').getElements('.selector');
```

html

```
<input type="text" class="others selector" ..../>
<input ... />
```

Can anyone confirm this?

Comment: no. can't get 1.2.4 anymore. given that it has a reliance on ua sniffing (which IE11 broke for trident) and reliance on feature detection of deprecated/changed features in IE and FF since it predates latest versions of both, you should not be using it. for 1.2.x, got to 1.2.6 or just take the plunge and go 1.4.5 with compat. http://jsfiddle.net/uFfDM/ works fine with 1.2.6 in IE9 and IE10 - `semver` is there for a reason. always try to stick to latest patch ver and if possible, minor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not know the reasons but $$ works for me.

it works if I use

```
$$('.selector')
```

instead of

```
$('indvNameId').getElements('.selector');
```